# Difference between row counts

Tags: sql, sqlite

I feel like this should be easy, but I can't figure it out ..

Let's say I have two tables

```
  x y
1 1 2
2 2 3
3 3 4
```

and

```
   x y
1  4 2
2 16 1
3  5 1
4  5 3
```

and I want to find the difference between the row counts (so 4-3 here).

I tried

```
ALTER TABLE table1 ADD COLUMN TBL CHAR DEFAULT "Table 1";
ALTER TABLE table2 ADD COLUMN TBL CHAR DEFAULT "Table 2";

SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM
  (SELECT *
   FROM table1
   UNION SELECT *
   FROM table2 )
GROUP BY TBL ;
```

which does give me the individual row counts but ... not the difference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the counts individually and subtract.

```
select (select count(*) from table1)-(select count(*) from table2)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to get the difference of the number of rows in two tables, try:

```
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table1) - (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table2)
```

Count gives the value of rows, and in sql, select (simple arithmetic calculation) gives the answer of the expression.

Or do you mean something else?